# OSX: How to store objects in plist file in an OO way

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I feel a little dumbfounded. I know how to store any kind of "plist supporting" data in a preferences file, such as NSArray, NSDictionary, NSString and their CF counterparts. No problem there.

Now I like to store the values of my custom object this way. I had thought that if I implement some kind of serialization/archiving protocol, I could get NSUserDefaults to understand my class just like it understand NSDictionary.

E.g, implementing the NSCoding protocol should give the NSUserDefaults code all that it needs: I give it the key names along with the values as plist compatible types (NSString, mostly in my case). But my encoder doesn't even get invoked. :(

Then I thought that there must be at least some function that generates a NSDictionary from the NSCoding protocol, so that I can then send this dict to store in the prefs. Ideally, there'd by something like the NSKeyedArchiver that I pass any NSCoding compatible object and it gives me a NSDictionary, and vice versa. But that doesn't appeat to exist in Apple's framework.

Do I have to write that really myself? I'd expect this would be a quite common need.

Note: I realize that NSKeyedArchiver generates a binary plist, which I could write as a plist file. But that's not what I want. I want to *add* the contents of this object to my app's prefs plist file, i.e. I want to store both my object and other prefs data in the plist file. That's what doesn't seem to be possible with the given functions.

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently just adding objects to an NSDictionary then calling NSDictionary's    "writeToFile:atomically:" method. I'm mostly adding strings, and an image as NSData, but I believe anything I add to the NSDictionary that implements the NSCoding protocol should get written to the file.

Then later when I call NSDictionary's initWithContentsOfFile everything gets put back in the dictionary as it had been. Would this work for you - letting the dictionary take care of the serialization stuff?

Comment: No, this does not solve it - I know I can write a Dictionary with CFPropertyList conforming contents.

However, I want to add a NSCoding-conforming Dictionary to my default Preferences file.

I want an Archiver converts an arbitrary Object<NSCoding> into a Dictionary holding only types of CFPropertyList, so that I can then store this in my Prefs.

I realize that I can write such a Archiver on my own, I just thought this should exist already, and I've just not found it.